# Trying to convert jQuery calls to knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have some code that I need to convert from jQuery calls to knockout.js syntax. I've been trying everything, and I'm completely fried. Argh!

Quick overview of what I'm trying to accomplish:
On click of one of the links, I need the toggleButton knockout function to run (this works beautifully), but additionally, I need what I've clicked to have the class of "active" added, and then all of the other links to have the class of "active" removed.

HTML in question:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#" id="all" class="active" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'All')">All</a>
    <a href="#" id="child" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'Children')">Children's</a>
    <a href="#" id="indie" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'Independent')">Independent</a>
    <a href="#" id="spir" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'Spiritual')">Spiritual/Religious</a>
    <a href="#" id="trad" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'Traditional')">Traditional</a>
    <a href="#" id="univ" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'University')">University</a>
    <a href="#" id="used" data-bind="click: toggleButton.bind($data,'Used')">Used</a>
</div>
```

.js in question:

```
function setActive(elem) {
    // Remove active class from any current element that has it.
    for (var u=0; u < elem.length; u++) {
        if (elem.hasClass("active")) {
            elem.removeClass("active")
        }
    }
    // Add active class to the clicked item
    $(event.target).addClass("active");
}
setActive($('#myTopnav').children());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that one. It is simpler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("a").not(this).removeClass("active");

});
```

});

Comment: Thanks Piotr... but I have to use knockout. I can't use jQuery.